# How to create row selector for recursive template in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-lists

From recursive list of items

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu_sublevel.html">
    id:{{item.id}}
    <ul ng-if="item.subs">
        <li ng-repeat="item in item.subs" ng-click="openItem(item)" ng-include="'menu_sublevel.html'">
            id:{{item.id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu.items" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-include="'menu_sublevel.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

and effect

```
 id:0
    ...id:4
    ...id:5
       ...id:16
       ...id:17
       ...id:18
    ...id:6
       ...id:20
       ...id:21
       ...id:22
```

I want to have selected one at time item.
When i write nested list without recursion i use `id` and on every level I have method for item selection and i chceck `

> levelOneItemSelected.id === item.id

How to select child with id 16 and have his parent with id 5 opened and next parent with id 0 opened while changing selection closes opened items.

Comment: You'd need to keep back-reference to the parent on each `item`, something like `item.parent`, and traverse up the tree in `openItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, upon invocation of `openItem(item)`, you also want to select/open its ancestors, then its best to have the reference from `item` to its parent, for example, `item.$$parent`. That would enable you to traverse the `item`'s ancestors and modify them. Conceptually speaking, it would look like so:

```
$scope.openItem(item){
  item.isOpen = true;
  while (item.$$parent){
    item = item.$$parent;
    item.isOpen = true;
  }
}
```

So, one way is to pre-process your items and set the `.$$parent` property accordingly.

If you don't like the idea of changing the `item` object (could be your domain model), you could always pre-process your domain model and produce a view model that wraps a domain model. It would look like so (in concept):

```
$scope.menu = [
  { $$parent: null,
    item: {id: 0, subs: [
      { $$parent: parentObj, // points to its parent
        item: {id: 10, subs: [...]}
      }
    ]}
  },
  // etc ...
]
```

But if you don't want to modify either, you could use the fact that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope and instantiate the `$$ancestors` property at each scope level. (Notice also, that `ng-click` should be on the displayed item, not on the `<li>` for subitems):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu_sublevel.html">
    <span ng-click="openItem(item, $$ancestors)"
          ng-class="{'open': item.isOpen}">id:{{item.id}}</span>

    <ul ng-if="item.subs" 
        ng-init="$$p = $$ancestors.slice(); $$p.push(item)">

        <li ng-repeat="item in item.subs" 
            ng-init="$$ancestors = $$p"
            ng-include="'menu_sublevel.html'">
            id:{{item.id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu.items" 
        ng-init="$$ancestors = []"
        ng-include="'menu_sublevel.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Then, in the controller, `openItem` needs to change:

```
var currentOpenItem = null,
    currentOpenItemAncestors = [];

$scope.openItem = function(item, ancestors){
   // closes the currently open item and its ancestors
   closeItem(currentOpenItem, currentOpenItemAncestors);

   currentOpenItem = item;
   currentOpenItemAncestors = ancestors;

   openItem(item, ancestors);
}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mY0ARGTHwBb74YHJKTG9?p=preview)**

The drawback of this approach is that it offloads some of the logic to the View and makes the View more complex and your controller less testable: